# Delphi VCL: Control align and size constraint

Tags: delphi, alignment, scrollbar, vcl

I would like to know, if there is a common desision for issue described below.

Let's consider the situation: I have a form with some controls, which captions and fonts could be changed on loading.
I want controls to be resized when form is resizing. Also I want control's captions to be clearly visible, if it possible. If it not, I want form to have scrollbar.

I thought I could use control constraints and anchors to resolve the situation. But if i use anchors scrollbar won't be shown. Also I have to calculate constraints because i don't know controls' fonts and captions' at design mode.

So I'm looking for some component or well-known algorithm which could help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: The only automatic approach to this sort of thing is to use lots of containers with align, alignwithmargins, margins and autosize properties. Using just anchors will get you to a situation where things adjust to the user resizing the form but won't deal with internal changes causing controls to resize.  I have a number of applications where forms completely readjust themselves but it is quite tricky to build up.  You are somewhat limited by depending on controls with autosize capability but this can still achieve quite a lot.  The only way to learn this sort of stuff is to practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that an already solution exist for your requirements, so I think you will have to work out a solution yourself.

I think that for a similar requirement you will have to use the OnResize event of the form and Resize/Reposition your components manually, in addition to this I think that you could use a TScrollBox component as a container and when the user resize the Form under a certain bound(that you will decide), you can set the AutoScroll property to true on the TScrollBox to let the scrollbar appear .